# Twilio JWT Token expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am using twilio voice call and it is working properly. But the twilio jwt token ends every hour. For this, the user has to refresh the page every hour.
My question is how to extend the token time in nodejs.

I am using this code to generate a token

```
var twilio = require('twilio');
var client = twilio(config.accountSid, config.authToken);
const ClientCapability = twilio.jwt.ClientCapability;

app.get('/token', (request, response) => {   
    const capability = new ClientCapability({
        accountSid: config.accountSid,
        authToken: config.authToken
    });
    capability.addScope(
        new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
            applicationSid: config.applicationSid 
        })
    );
    const token = capability.generateToken();
    // Include token in a JSON response
    response.send({
        token: token,
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/capability-tokens

Here, we generate a token that's only valid for ten minutes. The expires argument expects time in seconds.

```
capability = ClientCapabilityToken(account_sid, auth_token, ttl=600)
print(capability.to_jwt())
```

Comment: Please see it, it's worked  in node js by this
const capability = new ClientCapability({
        accountSid: config.accountSid,
        authToken: config.authToken,
        ttl=600
    });

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Access tokens do have limited lifespans. As Ankush answered, you can set a different `ttl` up to 24 hours.

Better yet is to use the [Twilio Access Manager](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/access-token-lifecycle). It is available as part of twilio-common for JavaScript, or the Access Manager package on iOS and Android.

The AccessManager will fire off two events that you can hook into. Firstly, when a token is near expiry, it will fire a token expired event. Hook into that event and when you receive it, *generate a new token from your server*. You can then set that new token in the AccessManager.

Once that token is set, the AccessManager will fire a token updated event which you can listen for and update the token in your Twilio Voice Client (or Chat, Video or Sync client, depending on what you are using).

To see how to download, install and use the Access Manager in detail for each of these platforms, take a look at the [Access Token life cycle and Access Manager documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/access-token-lifecycle).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: The link you provided only talks about chat. There is no mention of voice on that page and the voice docs make absolutely no mention of how one would go about updating the voice device with the new token once one has been obtained. Nor is there any mention of what would happen should the token expire during a voice call...

Comment: You’re right, chat and voice used to be handled the same and the chat docs were the best version I could share, but this answer was from two years ago. Now, a [`Twilio.Device` will emit an “offline” event](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#offline) when the token expires and you should call `setup` with a new token to reconnect it.

Comment: Hi @philnash I having similar sort of similar my event fires when a token in about to expire and it does says its updated but my some how my twillio chat client never connects after that, do i need to fetch a new token or am I missing something here.

Comment: @DeepKSOreadytohelp when your token expires you do need to fetch a new one and use that to update the client. What are you doing?